# Reconnect websocket rxjs

Tags: websocket, rxjs, redux-observable

I'm trying to get my websocket code to automatically attempt a reconnect (indefinitely) until successful. By sending a "ping" message every x seconds, I can detect when a pipe is broken, and the `closeObserver` is called.

However, I'm not sure how to get a reconnect sequence to initiate.

```
const notificationConnectionEpic: Epic<ActionTypes, any, RootState> = (
  action$,
  state$
) =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(actions.connectNotificationPipeline.request)),
    switchMap(async action => {
      const resp = await requireValidToken(action$, state$, params =>
        AdminHubs.getHubNotificationsToken({
          ...params,
          id: action.payload.hubId
        })
      );

      return resp.pipe(
        switchMap(v => {
          if (isAction(v)) {
            return of(v);
          }
          if (!v.ok) {
            return of(
              actions.connectNotificationPipeline.failure({
                hubId: action.payload.hubId,
                error: v.error
              })
            );
          }

          const webSocketOpen$ = new Subject();
          const webSocketClose$ = new Subject();
          const webSocket$ = webSocket<AdminHubs.HubNotification>({
            url: v.value,
            openObserver: webSocketOpen$,
            closeObserver: webSocketClose$
          });

          const message$ = webSocket$.pipe(
            map(message => actions.receiveNotification({ message })),
            takeUntil(action$.ofType(HubActionConsts.NOTIFICATION_PIPE_CLOSED))
          );

          const ping$ = interval(1000).pipe(
            map(_ => webSocket$.next("ping" as any)),
            ignoreElements()
          );

          const open$ = webSocketOpen$.pipe(
            take(1),
            map(_ =>
              actions.connectNotificationPipeline.success({
                hubId: action.payload.hubId
              })
            )
          );

          const close$ = webSocketClose$.pipe(
            // called when a network drop happens. handle reconnect?
          ); // also happens on net error
          return merge(message$, open$, ping$, close$);
        })
      );
    }),
    mergeMap(v => v)
  );
```

Comment: why not use ondisconnect event

Comment: there is no onDisconnect observer for the websocket , and even then how would I do the reconnect?

Comment: are you using any web socket library

Comment: rxjs has a websocket observer implementation im using.

Comment: take a look here https://itnext.io/websocket-error-handling-with-rxjs-17125c6f2159

Comment: Unfortunately that way of doing a retryWhen doesn't work, because I'm not getting an exception when the pipe is disconnected. It instead calls the websocketClose$ handler.

Comment: If I were u I will just creat my own socket class abstraction
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/onclose

Comment: @AlexanderMattoni did you ever get the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

When the WebSocket connection closes, just dispatch `actions.connectNotificationPipeline.request` again. That will re-run this code and create a new WebSocket connection.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this the last few weeks and decided to create [a package called SuperSocket](https://github.com/getshippr/supersocket) - in case it helps anyone! It should work as a drop in replacement for the WebSocket observer implementation you are using.

SuperSocket sits on top of the existing WebSocket implementation and, amongst other features,  make sure it reconnects until it successfully does. Of course you can setup a max retry to avoid infinite loop and unnecessary CPU load :)